# How would I implement brute-force that would attack TripleDES using Java?

Tags: java, encryption, brute-force, des, tripledes

I have been working on my science project when I wanted to perform an experiment where I would test how secure TripleDES is by brute-forcing it. TripleDES is composed of three keys, each 56-bits (plus 8 parity-bits), where each of the keys can be two modes, decryption or encryption. Thus, there are eight possible combinations (As Listed Here) :

[image]

Using this principle, how would I design a Java program which would brute-force all possible keys for TripleDES and possibly find the original plain-text?

Here is what I have tried for single DES:

```
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class DES64 {

    public static byte[] generateKey(byte [] encoded_key2, int N_BYTE) {

        byte[] encoded_key = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < N_BYTE; i++) {
            encoded_key[8 - N_BYTE + i] = encoded_key2[i];
        }

        return encoded_key;

    }

    public static byte[] des_attack(String plaintext, byte[] encoded_key2, int N_BYTE) throws Exception {

        byte[] encoded_key = generateKey(encoded_key2, N_BYTE);

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(encoded_key, "DES");  

        byte[] initVector = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x10, 0x01, 0x04, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02 };
        AlgorithmParameterSpec algParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initVector);

        Cipher m_encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        m_encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, algParamSpec);

        Cipher m_decrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        byte[] clearText = plaintext.getBytes();

        byte[] encryptedText = m_encrypter.doFinal(clearText);

        int guess = 0;
        int N_COMB = (int) Math.pow(2.0, (N_BYTE) * 7);
        System.out.println("All possible combiantions : " + N_COMB);

        BitSet encoding_attack_key = new BitSet(8 * N_BYTE);
        encoding_attack_key.clear();
        byte[] mykey = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < N_COMB; i++) {

            String tmp = Integer.toBinaryString(i);

            int z = 0;
            int j = tmp.length() - 1;
            while (j >= 0) {

                if (z != 63 && z != 55 && z != 47 && z != 39 && z != 31 && z != 23 && z != 15 && z != 7) {
                    if (tmp.charAt(j) == '1') {
                        encoding_attack_key.set(z);

                    }
                    j--;
                    z++;
                } else {
                    z++;
                }

            }

            for (int k = 0; k < N_BYTE; k++) {

                if (encoding_attack_key.get(k * 8, (k * 8) + 7).cardinality() % 2 != 0) {

                    encoding_attack_key.set((k * 8) + 7);

                }
            }

            if (guess % 1000000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Guess : " + guess + " out of : " + N_COMB + " ------- "
                        + 100 * (guess + 0.0) / N_COMB + "% completed");

            }
            guess++;

            int len = encoding_attack_key.toByteArray().length;
            mykey[0] = len >= 8 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[7] : 0x0;
            mykey[1] = len >= 7 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[6] : 0x0;
            mykey[2] = len >= 6 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[5] : 0x0;
            mykey[3] = len >= 5 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[4] : 0x0;
            mykey[4] = len >= 4 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[3] : 0x0;
            mykey[5] = len >= 3 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[2] : 0x0;
            mykey[6] = len >= 2 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[1] : 0x0;
            mykey[7] = len >= 1 ? encoding_attack_key.toByteArray()[0] : 0x0;

            SecretKey key_g = new SecretKeySpec(mykey, "DES");
            m_decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key_g, algParamSpec);
            try {
                byte[] text_g = m_decrypter.doFinal(encryptedText);
                String plain_text = new String(text_g);

                if (plain_text.equals(new String(clearText))) {

                    return mykey;

                }

            } catch (BadPaddingException ee) {

            }

            encoding_attack_key.clear();

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String plaintext = "example";
        int nbyte = 4;
        byte[] b = new byte[] { 0x6, 0x7, 0x35, 0x09 };

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        byte[] ris = des_attack(plaintext, b, b.length);
        long estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime);

        String kris = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ris.length; i++)
            kris += " " + ris[i] + " ";
        System.out.println("PLAINTEXT : " + plaintext + "      ESTIMATED TIME: " + estimatedTime
                + "     NFREE_BYTE_KEY: " + nbyte + "    KEY: " + kris + "\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: A little history might be helpful: [*Advanced Wireless Technologies built 1856 custom ASIC DES chips (called Deep Crack or AWT-4500), housed on 29 circuit boards of 64 chips each.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Triple-DES or actually TDEA is a standard](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-67/rev-2/final). It is just DES-EDE by the way, not any of the other. Of course the *decryption* is performed using the DED order. Triple-DES has a two-key and three-key mode (disregarding the one that simply reverts to DES for backwards compatibility).

The two key Triple-DES mode (with a so called DES ABA key as the A key gets reused for the final DES cipher) has a strength of about 80 bits in the worst case. This is somewhat close to being brute forced, being only 2^16 times harder to brute force than the Shattered attack performed by using Google's infrastructure. Not something you'd do with Java and a PC in itself.

The *strength* of three key Triple-DES with DES ABC keys is about 2^112, there is no way to brute force your way out of that. So the simple answer is: "you don't" with Java or without.

Comment: Quite often Triple-DES CBC mode is used, which is vulnerable against padding oracle attacks. Furthermore, the small block size of TDES makes it vulnerable in CTR mode. So if there is no protection by a MAC, or if there is IV reuse etc., the actual implementation may be vulnerable. And then there are side channel attacks as well....